# android adapter getView does not repaint image on scroll and notification event

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Hi I have a list and I am redrawing the image based on the setting on notification. Basically I can't figure out why the image is NOT redrawn. I see in the log that it gets set.

Odly I tried to set a textview in the same view and that works fine. What's wrong with the image? can anybody tell me?

Thank you in advance!

```
   @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

    //---- if the view is null, create a new one from xml
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.drawable.my_item_layout, parent, false);
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mybg);
            }

    CustomItem item = super.getItem(position);

    if (item != null)
    {
    TextView title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    ImageView image1= (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);


    title.setText(item.getName());


    if (item.getMyNotificationChangedItemState()){
         image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimagePink); <- this does not get updated 
        title.setTextColor(this._context.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_text_pink));   

 else 
       {
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimageBlue);
title.setTextColor(this._context.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_text_blue));  

       }
    }
```

So my Blue image & text gets shown when the list gets loaded the first time. Once notification happens I first update to change the one that's currrently PINK to BLUE and then change the one that I need to update from BLUE to PINK depending on previous and current index of the items in the list. The update is done on the activity. I can see the log prints the fact that getMyNotificationChangedItemState() is changed, and the image is being set, but I never see the change in the UI.

Why does that work for TEXTVIEW and does not work for IMAGEVIEW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adapters, getView() only gets called when the current view is invalidated.

Have you made sure to call invalidate() on the view in question after you make the notification?

As another sanity check, what about switching pink and blue and trying again?

Comment: getView() is def being called. I am logging the actual event & all the data. It 100% happens. The proof is the text color changes.

Comment: did you try switching blue and pink, to make sure it isn't a resource problem?

Comment: aha thank you for the idea! One image was xml selector the other one was an actual image. Switching it to XML selector worked! Now I don't know why that happens but it works :))